# Does Newtonian mechanics define an absolute rotational reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames, machs-principle

I note that there are several question related to absolute rotation so this may be a duplicate but I didn’t see an exact double. In any case, mine is this:

In a hypothetical universe made up by only our solar system, one would not have a rotational reference in absence of distant stars. Therefore any planet could be considered to hover about the sun.

If we add the assumption that our modern mechanics also holds in this universe, no such hovering can occur. On the contrary, our mechanics require all planets to be in motion with given and exact lateral velocities around the sun.

If we expand the universe to include a distant star, it would seem that we could determine its relative angular velocity based on our calculation of the solar system alone, thereby giving us an absolute rotational reference, also true if we included the rest of the universe (which would also justify our initial assumption on mechanics).

Is this actually the case?

Comment: Matter distributions break Galileo as well as Lorentz invariance and they make space "effectively" inhomogeneous and anisotropic. This kind of symmetry breaking is usually not what is being meant by the fundamental symmetries of empty space.

Comment: Re, "...expand the universe to include a distant star..." Just one? But then how could you tell whether or not your local system was rotating on an axis parallel to your line of sight to the distant star?

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude that determining a *relative* angular velocity of a distant object implies any absolute rotational frame of reference, where do you find that the symmetry between the solar system and this distant star breaks down?

Comment: This must have been asked before.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I admit I was looking at this as an excercise in two dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

Rotational motion is an accelerated or non-inertial motion. It is invariant, regardless of any external reference. Regardless of the rest of the universe, or even the rest of the solar system, we can always confirm whether a given frame is rotating or not based only on local measurements.

Comment: but you can't determine (locally) if you are or are not rotating w.r.t to the distant stars.

Comment: But you can determine locally if a gyroscope in your frame precesses

Comment: I hope so, but if your frame is near a "rotating" blackhole, a stationary gyroscope will be precessing w.r.t frames far from the blackhole, which for me, precludes an absolute non-rotating frame, mostly.

Comment: @JEB you appear to be switching "invariant" with "global"

Answer (score 2):

Mach's principle is based on the idea that all the forces and laws of physics depend only on the *relative* distances and angles *between* particles, so we cannot tell using physics and therefore (by a version of Leibniz' Principle of the Identity of Indiscernibles) *there is no physical difference* between two physical situations where all the lengths and angles are the same.

In a Newtonian world, distances and angles are only defined within each 3D time slice. So you can shear and slide the time slices relative to one another arbitrarily, like a stack of loose sheets of paper, and detect no difference. Translate them horizontally, rotate them however you like, the distances and angles within each sheet remain invariant, and thus a Newtonian observer would detect no difference. These degrees of freedom are physically meaningless - they have no observable consequences.

However, in special relativity simultaneity is no longer absolute, and you can define distances and angles between events in *different* time slices. You can talk about the distance (the spacetime interval) to some event in the future or the past. Only spacetime intervals are invariant with different reference frames, 3D lengths are not, and since the physics cannot depend on an imaginary coordinate sytem, the physics must be dependent only on the spacetime intervals and angles defined in the relativistic way. (Strictly, forces and effects can only propagate on and within the past and future lightcones, but these still interlock rigidly enough to fix all other distances.)

These fixed distances between time slices lock them together, eliminating the freedom to slip and slide them relative to one another. They form a rigid block. The block can still translate and rotate as a whole, but you can no longer translate or rotate one time slice relative to those in its future or past, because to some moving observer, those events are simultaneous.

Inertial particles move on straight lines through spacetime. Particles rotating about a central point move along a helix, like a spiral staircase. Although distances between them in horizontal slices can be made to match up, when you add the cross-links between different times, the distances and angles are completely different. These two situations are not physically the same, and can be distinguished locally by measuring distances in relatively moving reference frames.

We still have identical physics in inertial reference frames moving linearly with respect to one another, because this happens to be an isometry of spacetime. A 'boost' or Minkowski rotation about a spacelike axis leaves distances and angles invariant. But a rotating reference frame corresponds to a *twisted* spacetime frame, and this is *not* an isometry of spacetime.

Things get a little more complicated in general relativity, because spacetime can be curved, and this distorts those distances and angles. We can indeed 'twist' one part of spacetime relative to another, so they have 'different' rotational reference frames. This is called 'frame dragging' or the Lense-Thirring effect. A rotating mass 'drags' the surrounding spacetime around with it, twisting up lengths and angles between different times in the same sort of way as spinning does. It has been noted that the gravitational effect of a rotating shell of matter surrounding the observer drags the observer's rotational reference frame to match its own rotation. So the distant stars and galaxies do determine the particular rotational reference frame we experience, ensuring they are aligned. However, even if they were not there, there still would have to be such a rotational reference frame, purely as a result of distances having to be defined between different timeslices. The network of distances and angles between particles don't just make a rigid 3D grid at each instant of time, but a rigid 4D block of spacetime, that can distinguish between straight and curved worldlines.